# ListViewAnimations Swipe and Dismiss

Tags: android, listview

i'm using Niek Haarman ListViewAnimations. I want to implement Google Card Now animation on the ListView with Contextual Undo([Swipe & Dismiss](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/blob/master/example/src/com/haarman/listviewanimations/itemmanipulationexamples/SwipeDismissActivity.java)).

Can i using Contextual Undo like this snippet code bellow

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(final AbsListView listView, final int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
    for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
        mAdapter.remove(position);
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Removed positions: " + Arrays.toString(reverseSortedPositions), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void setContextualUndoAdapter() {
    ContextualUndoAdapter adapter = new ContextualUndoAdapter(mAdapter, R.layout.undo_row, R.id.undo_row_undobutton, this);
    adapter.setAbsListView(getListView());
    getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

on one of this example([GoogleCardsActivity](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/blob/master/example/src/com/haarman/listviewanimations/GoogleCardsActivity.java#L68))? I mean i need to show undo button before user swap from left to right and then card gone.

If it can, how to do that? many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, i got way to do that. Here are snippet code bellow to do that :

```
        mGoogleCardsAdapter = new GoogleCardsAdapter(this);
        SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter swingBottomInAnimationAdapter = new SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter(new ContextualUndoAdapter(mGoogleCardsAdapter, R.layout.undo_row, R.id.undo_row_undobutton, this));
        swingBottomInAnimationAdapter.setInitialDelayMillis(300);
        swingBottomInAnimationAdapter.setAbsListView(listView);
```